# Regex matches always returns false

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I'm trying to validate user input so that the only allowed characters in a string are A-Z, a-z, _, - and whitespace. To do that I wrote the following code:

```
val regex = Regex("[\\w\\s-]")
val flag = regex.matches("Hello Overlay")
```

But the value of `flag` is false and I can't figure out why.

Comment: are you supposed to use double backslashes? https://regex101.com/ might be a good place to test it out on

Comment: @rong yeah, you need to escape them in Java/Kotlin, unless you use the Kotlin string literal (surrounded by `"""`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the whole string meeting a pattern use

```
val regex = Regex("[\\w\\s-]+")
```

Or, to avoid overescaping:

```
val regex = Regex("""[\w\s-]+""")
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/DEMFH24342). Note that `matches` requires a full string match, but `[\w\s-]` only matches  a single character.

```
val regex = Regex("""[\w\s-]+""")
val flag = regex.matches("Hello Overlay")
println(flag)  // => true
```

Comment: I want the whole string to conform to the regular expression not a substring

Comment: @RishabhJain I updated the answer to only contain the relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
val regex = Regex("""[\w\s-]+""")
val flag = regex.matches("Hello Overlay")
println(flag)  // => true
```